# How to get android file association to support dots in the path?

Tags: android, path, wildcard, manifest, file-association

In my android apps manifest I have a couple of file types I want associated with my app.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
    <data android:host="*"/>
    <data android:scheme="file"/>
    <data android:scheme="content"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myType1"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Tapping on a file in my downloads folder named

```
downloads/TEST.myType1
```

will load with my app. However

```
downloads/this.is.a.test.folder/TEST.myType1
```

will not.

The only way I've found to support dots within file paths is

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myType1"/> <!-- Supports 0 extra dots -->
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.myType1"/> <!-- Supports 1 extra dot -->
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.myType1"/> <!-- Supports 2 extra dots -->
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.myType1"/> <!-- Supports 3 extra dots -->
```

Surely Androids mock regex for pathPatterns isn't so basic that this is the only reasonable option, anyone know of a cleaner solution?

Comment: Try `<data android:pathPattern="[\\s\\S]*\\.myType1"/>`. Or ``<data android:pathPattern="(?:\\.|.)*\\.myType1"/>``

Comment: They don't work because from Google documentation on pathPattern they only support the * operator and \ operator in their "regex".

Comment: Then it is not a *regular* expression, it is a *wildcard* pattern.